# Regressive call in promise

Tags: node.js, promise, q

Is there any easy way to do recursive call using promise. Here is my sample.

```
function getData() {
   var result=[];
   var deferred = Q.defer();
   (function fetchData(pageno){
     var options = {
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'example.com/test',
        qs:{
          pageNo: pageno
        }
     }

    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error)throw new Error(error);

        if (body.hasMorePage == true) { //checking is there next page 
            result.push(body)
            fetchData(++body.pageno); // getting next page data
        } else {
             deferred.resolve(result); // promise resolve when there is no more page
        }
    });
   })(0);
    return deferred.promise;
}


getData().then(function(data){
     console.log(data)
});
```

Let's consider API is giving more data in consecutive calls. in order to collect all the data, I need to use some parameter (EX:hasMorePage) from previous call response. I need to go regressive call only for obtaining this scenario, but I would like to know a better(Promise) way.

Most welcome.

Comment: No need for `Q`, you can just use `new Promise(...)`, and you can use `async`/`await` to chain your requests in a `for(...)` loop.

Comment: This scenario how can I use for loop, based on the previous call only I will decide need to go next call or need to resolve it.

Comment: See my answer. It shows what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
async function request(options, callback) {
  // simulate server response of example.com/test with 1 second delay
  const totalNumberOfPages = 3;
  const pageNo = options.qs.pageNo;
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  const hasMorePages = pageNo < totalNumberOfPages;
  const body = { hasMorePages };
  callback(void 0, { body }, body);
}


function getPage(pageNo) {
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'example.com/test',
    qs: { pageNo }
  };
  return new Promise(resolve => request(options, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log('response received', response);
    if(error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
    resolve(body);
  }));
}

async function getData() {
    const result = [];
    for(let i = 1, hasMorePages = true; hasMorePages; i++) {
        const body = await getPage(i);
        result.push(body);
        hasMorePages = body.hasMorePages;
    }
    return result;
}

getData().then(data => console.log('RESULT', data));
```

Comment: I think it should work. Will see, Is there any better way. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "better way"?

Comment: I expected more suggestion from others

Comment: What do you mean by "better way"?  bcz async and await supporting node v8. Is there any other way which supports all versions.